# WKWebView goBack takes me to top of local html page

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have some html pages as in-app help and I use a WKWebView to show them, which includes a "back" button calling `goBack`.

Everything works smoothly, except the back button always takes you to the very top of the previous local html page (instead of the scroll position of the page where the link you clicked was), although it works fine if you follow further links to remote content and use "back" to go from one remote page to the previous remote page.

I have removed everything extra to debug this, like post navigation etc, so currently I am simply making a call to:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"help" withExtension:@"html"]]];
```

Then just `[webView goBack]` and back to the top of the page you go. It doesn't matter if you follow a link to another internal html or an external page. But, as I said if you follow a link to an external page and then another external page, the first back takes you to the correct position of the first external page.

Any ideas? It makes browsing internal html annoying.

Edit: OK, it might have to do with the actual html - there is one page where back works, trying to figure out the difference. Everything before the `<body>` is the same and all pages pass w3.org html4 transitional validation.

Comment: `var backForwardList: WKBackForwardList { get }` of the WKWebView should help you find out the current stack of pages that you can go forward and backward to and figure out which page is missing from list.

Comment: @dispatchMain This is not about a missing page. It takes you back to the correct page, but not at the correct scroll position, just the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tentative answer, I'd appreciate it if someone can improve on it or explain the mechanics.
It seems that "goBack" takes you to the top of the previous page if that page has an element in its content whose width is greater than the original width the webview tried to flow the content in. In my case for example, as I am using Dynamic Type fonts, for some text sizes some headers and some links were too long.
The immediate solution is to add `body {word-wrap:break-word;}`. This is a bit of a "hammer" solution as it does have some unintended consequences, so I am trying to find an alternative (currently playing with the `viewport` meta in case it can help).

I have not found a way to fix `goBack` behaviour for `loadHTMLString` - when I try to first write the string to a file, `goBack` does work, but I have other issues (can no longer follow links to html files in my bundle).